# GIT block two branches from merging pre-commit

Tags: git, merge, branch, hook

How could I stop branch A from merging into Branch B with pre-commit hook, using PHP. I want to make sure that with this hook script it won't be possible to merge this 2 branches to each other!.

Thanks in adavanced for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to check if either branch is merged to another and exit with something except 0 (1 e.g.).

Here's a hint for you with examples in PHP: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy